# Characterization of upper semicontinuous functions

Tags: general-topology

I want to prove this:

Let $X$ be a topological space and $f: X \to \mathbb{R}$. If $\forall x \in X, \forall \varepsilon >0 \quad \exists U_x \subset X :\quad f(y) < f(x) + \varepsilon \quad \forall y \in U_x$ then $f^{-1}((-\infty;a))$ is open in $X$ for every $a \in \mathbb{R}$, where $U_x$ is a neighborhood of $x$.

Attempt:

Let $a \in \mathbb{R}, x \in f^{-1}((-\infty;a)) \Rightarrow f(x)<a$
It exists $A \subset U_x$, $A$ open in $X$ s.t. $f(y) < f(x) + \varepsilon \quad \forall y \in A$. If $y \in A$ then $f(y) <a + \varepsilon \quad \forall \varepsilon >0 \Rightarrow f(y) \in (-\infty; a)$ and then $y \in f^{-1}((-\infty;a))$. And then I proved that $A \subset f^{-1}((-\infty;a))$. And than $f^{-1}((-\infty;a))$ is a neighborhood of each $x \in f^{-1}((-\infty;a))$ and then it is open.

Is it correct?

Comment: You cannot expect the same $\epsilon$ to work for every $ x$ such that $f(x)<a.$ See the A by Henno Brandsma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is essentially correct. You do not specify $\varepsilon$, though.
If $x \in A = f^{-1}[(-\infty, a)]$, where $a \in \mathbb{R}$, we want to show that $x$ is an interior point of $A$. We know that $f(x) < a$ so define $\varepsilon = a -f(x)>0$ The condition on $f$ gives us an open neighbourhood $U_x$ of such such that $$\forall p \in U_x: f(p) < f(x) + \varepsilon = a$$ which shows that $f[U_x] \subseteq (-\infty,a)$ so that $U_x \subseteq A$, showing $x \in \operatorname{Int}(A)$, as required.